# Why is $\sum_{g \in G} \rho(g) =0$ for any nontrivial irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $F$ be an arbitrary field, and $(\rho, V)$ be an irreducible representation of $G$. Then $$\sum_{g \in G} \rho(g) = \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{ if } \rho \neq 1_G, \\
> |G|1_V & \text{ if } \rho = 1_G.
> \end{cases}$$

The case when $\rho =1_G$ is clear. But why is the sum $0$ for nontrivial irreducible representations?

Thanks very much.

Comment: You probably want $G$ to be a finite group and $V$ to be a vector space over $F$.

Comment: You mean $g \neq 1_{G}$ (and $g = 1_{G}$) since $\rho : G \rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$.

Comment: @GilYoungCheong: I think he means what he wrote in this case. $1_G$ is simply the trivial representation.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks. Then I learn another notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Suppose that $x = \rho(\sum g) v \neq 0$ for some $v$.  What happens if you act $g \in G$ on $x$?  What does that mean for the subspace spanned by $x$?

Comment: I still don't quite see how this shows that $$\sum_{g\in G} \rho(g) = 0$$ for $\rho \neq 1_{G}$ (the non-trivial irred. representation). Could you explain what you mean when you ask "What happens if you act $g \in G$ on $x$".

Comment: "act g on x" means compute $\rho(g)(x)$